# Weird DNS behaviour

Tags: domain-name-system

We had a Rails app hosted on Linode that we moved to Heroku.
Its been 3 days since the switch of the DNS server and a user told us that sees the old version of the website on his iPad but the new version on his desktop PC.

I noticed that when I go to incognito on my chrome on **some** occasions I also get redirected on the old website.

Any idea what is causing this and if there is a way to handle it?

Comment: What is the domain in question?

Comment: @EEAA coincut.com. for reference we point to coincut.com.herokudns.com and Heroku does the magic

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS records look correct. Since the DNS records look correct, it may be a caching issue. The NS records from the TLD servers have a 48 hour TTL. So if has been less than 48 hours, since you updated the records, you may just have to wait.

You can check the caches on the DNS resolvers provided by your own ISP. It is likely one of them has an old record cached, and the rest have the new record.

Or you can try flushing.

---

Flush the DNS on the iPad

```
 Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.
```

Flush the DNS on your computer

Mac: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

PC: `ipconfig /flushdns`